# Convexity of a configuration of $n$ points

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Let's say we have $n$ points say in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $h$ points of the $n$ points where $n \ge h \ge 3$ are on the convex hull of this configuration.

How many ways are we able to create a non-convex set from this convex hull by moving at least one of the $h$ points on the convex hull? Would we need more information about the configuration? Is there a maximum number of the $h$ points that can be moved to create a non-convex set?

Comment: Are you imagining here that the set specified by the points is not in general the convex hull of the points, but instead the interior region of the polygon made by connecting the $h$ points along the boundary of the original convex hull?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct.

Comment: Ok, cool! So what happens if we move one of the $h$ points inwards so that one of the remaining $n-h$ interior points is now outside the polygon? Does the new set now simply no longer include that point, or do we have to "stretch around" that point convexly, so to speak? (Essentially I'm wondering why we have $n$ total points instead of $h$.)

Comment: The set of $n$ points consists of the $h$ points on the convex hull and then interior points, which there are total of $n-h$.

Comment: Right, no, I understand that, I'm just wondering if the remaining $n-h$ interior points have any effect on the sets we create when moving around the $h$ points, or if we can forget about them completely.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for clarifying. We can forget about them.

Comment: nice! now there's another question: what makes two "ways of moving points" the same? for instance, since these points are initially on the boundary of a convex hull, I can move any one of them sufficiently far along the line parallel to the line that goes through the two adjacent points on the polygon, and eventually get a bend. that gives an infinite number of ways on the face of it. is this not quite what you're asking?